# Should one table reference every other table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm working on an application that routinely gathers information from a large number of websites and saves it to a mysql database with a table for each site. The idea is to create a sort of customizable news feed.

- stackoverflow_table(id, url, title, date)
- reddit_table(id, title, url, author, date)
- github_commit_table(id,
  commit_message, author, repository,
  branch, date)
- twitter_table(id, tweet, author, url, date)
- etc...

I want the ability to request any number of news items and filter out certain sites too. As an example:

*Show newest 100 items but exclude items from Twitter and GitHub.*

It seems like the best way to handle this is to create a table that just has foreign keys and website names.

master_table(id, website, date, foreign_key)

and I can just query the foreign ids I need from this table.

Am I going about this horribly wrong?

Comment: try and let us know what is the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually been working on a similar site.  Not for other sites, but a kind of Facebook-like site for a niche community with newsfeeds from various sources.  I've been pondering this question very heavily the past couple of weeks.

One issue, probably not gamebreaking, but still an issue for me, is that since your `foreign_key` column isn't literally a foreign key due to referencing multiple tables, so it can't get the benefits from things such as referential integrity enforcement.

What I'm considering is making a GUID table that serves as the source of ids for all of the other tables, and having a table specifically dedicated to the news feed.  It might be defined as something like:

```
CREATE TABLE sources (
  id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  url VARCHAR(50) );

INSERT INTO sources (name, url) VALUES ('Stack Overflow', 'http://stackoverflow.com');
INSERT INTO sources (name, url) VALUES ('Reddit', 'http://www.reddit.com');
INSERT INTO sources (name, url) VALUES ('Github', 'http://github.com');
INSERT INTO sources (name, url) VALUES ('Twitter', 'http://twitter.com');
/* And so on... */

CREATE TABLE newsfeed (
  guid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  -- Note: NOT auto_increment!
  source_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL,
  text VARCHAR(256),
  ref_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (source_id) references sources (id) );
```

You could still store information about site postings in their own tables, but now you're just referencing the one newsfeed table for what to actually display on the page, with the ref_id being a pointer to individual source tables if someone wants to deep-dive into the information.  It's still not ideal because ref_id still isn't a true foreign key, but it's arguably a little better.

You might even want to do something like this instead of ref_id:

```
data TEXT,
```

with the contents of that column for any given entry a source-specific data payload.  For example, for Github posts, it could contain a JSON string such as:

```
{"commit_message":"Updated global variable namespace.",
  "author":"King Skippus","repository":"Ibuware"}
```

Comment: Oh, in case it's not evident, the guid column would contain a system-wide identifier unique among all source tables.  So guid 1 might be in the Reddit table, guids 2 and 3 in the Twitter table, guid 4 in the Stack Overflow table, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas which you may find useful:
As you said, you can put all common properties in one table :
`master_table(id, website, date, foreign_key,url)`
Then create another table:
`details_tables(id, master_id, property_name, property_value, property_type)` which is used to retrieve data specific to each site. I believe it will give more flexibility than storing everything in json . If you expect many records in these tables, consider using partitioning.

You can also keep the existing table structure, but add a view :
`SELECT 'Stack Overflow' as site_name, id, url, date

  FROM stackoverflow_table 
  UNION

  SELECT 'Reddit' as site_name, id, url, date

  FROM reddit_table 
  ...etc`

Comment: > I believe it will give more flexibility than storing everything in json. What do you think the deficiencies would be in just using JSON?

Comment: One day you may want to add some search functionality. I think parsing JSON using mysql can be a challenge.

Comment: I didn't intend to suggest that you have use JSON for the data field. I just meant that is one option. Obviously, anything that you think you may want to search on at some point should be in a separate, preferably indexed, column. The problem with UNION is that you cannot combine datasets with varying numbers of columns. How are you going to capture, for example, the repository and branch data from Github? If you have the extra data column, you don't have to create messy multi-table (and slow) UNIONs, and you can format it however you want, or even use different formats for different sites.

Answer (score -1):

A table for each site is the issue. As more sites come online you will end up with too many links.

Get a DBA/Architect involved to fix your data model and your links issue will disappear.

Comment: The answer to just about any question on Stack Overflow could be, "hire someone to fix your problem."  The OP may be doing this just as a non-commercial project, or he might not want to run to a DBA/architect even after this project is done.  Or maybe he wants to BE the DBA/architect that others get.

Comment: Well, i figured a table for each site would be appropriate since the information I collect from every site will vary wildly. Otherwise, it seems like I'd have one table with 40 fields. 

A lot of the information, Reddit post author for example, is meta data that doesn't need to be searchable. I considered just putting all non-searchable info into a JSON object.

only_table(id, date, website, JSON)

Also, DBA... this is just a small personal project. I don't know any DB people.

Comment: How is suggesting getting some expert help worthy of a downvote? This sounds like a complex problem and someone with experience may be needed to get it working properly.